# Does a hard disk still work (with reduced capacity) when one platter is removed?

Tags: hard-drive

When there is a hard disk with one damaged platter or head, can one platter be removed and the disk made workable again with reduced capacity?

The firmware might autodetect the number of available platters during power up. Maybe the same firmware is used across a HDD range and so supports drives with different numbers of platters.

Note: I am *not* asking about interchanging platters, but about reducing the number of platters.

Assume that the damaged platter or head can be removed in clean room conditions.

Comment: Hard drives have tolerances measured in microns not yards. If you opened it, it's dead. Forget it. Throw it away. You broke it irreparably when you opened it.

Comment: Repairing a hard disk? Not possible without intimate knowledge of the product internals, ... and it probably requires tools to (physically) calibrate it.

Comment: @Tetsujin: I know. There are possibilities and guides on the internet on even how to swap platters between identical drives, provided careful working in a clean environment. So, that should not be the _prinicipal_ problem.

Comment: Give it a try and post an answer. Sounds extremely non-standard and hardware dependent (like the answer would be), probably no other way to find out.

Comment: If you're comparing the cost of discarding a dead HD against the cost of clean facilities for multiple repeat operations over several years, then your point may be valid.

Comment: Even when a hard drive is repaired by a data recovery professional in a clean room and using all the special tools and following all the established procedures it is considered only a temporary repair appropriate only for data recovery. It is not considered sufficiently reliable for continued service. Removal of the platter must be considered a high risk procedure which even if done 100% correctly the results are far from certain. Go ahead if you wish but the chances of success are slim.

Comment: @JakeGould: Yes, you got me. In fact, after opening the drive the academic question if it would have been possible to use it with a removed platter if I had been opening it under clean room conditions came up. And I mixed up and simplified things here, which lead to "digging my own hole".

Comment: Theoretical questions don't work well here, I've voted it down because of that fact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is NO way to know what the firmware is really doing without reverse engineering it.

There is NOT a standard firmware or hardware platform for hard drives, only a standard host interface.

For a long time hard drives have supported "sector sparing", and will report when this occurs via SMART, but no information is provided on where the spare sectors are, etc.  Given this it's likely that the firmware would try to address defects on a sector level and not a platter level.

As @Tetsujin says, if you opened it, it's very very likely completely dead now.  Hard drive heads float *microns* above the drive surface, meaning normal particles in air will cause the head to crash.  Data recovery companies open hard drive platters in clean room conditions where there is no dust.

[image]

Image from [here](http://www.pcguide.com/ref/hdd/op/heads/opHeight-c.html).